# Ruby 1.9.3 doesn't run any unit tests when run in parallel

Tags: ruby, testunit, ruby-1.9.3

When run in parallel, Ruby 1.9.3 doesn't run any unit tests

Given the following code,

```
# Modified from https://gist.github.com/1334056/121396125ca4dd7ee1bb81536cce0754700f20fb
# replication.rb
require 'test/unit'
class TestTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_one
    assert true
  end

  def test_two
    assert true
  end
end
```

unit testing works when it's not run in parallel, but doesn't work when it's run in parallel:

```
$ ruby1.9.1 replication.rb 
Run options: 

# Running tests:

..

Finished tests in 0.000348s, 5740.7094 tests/s, 5740.7094 assertions/s.

2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

$ ruby1.9.1 replication.rb --jobs=2 --ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
Run options: --jobs=2 --ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

# Running tests:


Retrying...





Finished tests in 0.039012s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

For what it's worth, here's what happens when the debugging switch is on:

```
$ export RUBYOPT="-d"
$ ruby1.9.1 replication.rb 
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1243 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1252 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Run options: 

# Running tests:

..

Finished tests in 0.000350s, 5718.3539 tests/s, 5718.3539 assertions/s.

2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
$ ruby1.9.1 replication.rb --jobs=2 --ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1243 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1252 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Run options: --jobs=2 --ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

# Running tests:

Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1243 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1252 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1243 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1252 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/parallel.rb:149: warning: method redefined; discarding old on_parallel_worker?
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:11: warning: previous definition of on_parallel_worker? was here
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/parallel.rb:149: warning: method redefined; discarding old on_parallel_worker?
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:11: warning: previous definition of on_parallel_worker? was here
Exception `Errno::EPIPE' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/parallel.rb:125 - Broken pipe - <STDOUT>
Exception `Errno::EPIPE' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/parallel.rb:133 - Broken pipe - <STDOUT>

Retrying...





Finished tests in 0.033203s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I also tried requiring minitest, but that didn't have parallel testing available:

```
# mini_me.rb
# modified from http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest
require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestMeme < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_one
    assert true
  end

  def test_two
    assert true
  end
end
```

gives

```
$ ruby1.9.1 mini_me.rb --help
minitest options:
    -h, --help                       Display this help.
    -s, --seed SEED                  Sets random seed
    -v, --verbose                    Verbose. Show progress processing files.
    -n, --name PATTERN               Filter test names on pattern.
```

And here's the version of Ruby and ubuntu.

```
$ ruby1.9.1 --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

$ uname -a
Linux [redacted] 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've also run the first script using a recent commit of Ruby on OS X snow leopard (ruby 2.0.0dev (2012-05-05 trunk 35543) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]), and it didn't work there.

What am I doing wrong?

The following happens when I have multiple files, but don't explicitly use `Test::Unit::Runner`

test1.rb

```
require "test/unit"

class Test1 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_one
    assert true
  end
end
```

test2.rb

```
require "test/unit"

class Test2 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_two
    assert true
  end
end
```

test_all.rb

```
require_relative "test1"
require_relative "test2"
```

Trying using this approach:

```
$ ruby test_all.rb --basedir=. --jobs 2 --ruby /Users/agrimm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
Run options: --basedir=. --jobs 2 --ruby /Users/agrimm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby

# Running tests:


Retrying...





Finished tests in 0.075256s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0dev (2012-05-05 trunk 35543) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sora_h a maintainer of `test/unit`.

`test/unit` parallelizes for each test file.

You need to separate test file and `TestCase` to parallelize.

Sorry for inconvenience, but we can't parallelize for each `test_*` methods because there are some `test_*` methods can't run separately. (needs to be ordered)

You can use `Test::Unit::Runner` to run multiple files.

Thank you.